# помогите вывести данные в ajax запросе на экран

Tags: javascript, ajax

помогите вывести данные в ajax запросе на экран , скрипт на сервер грузится и обрабатывается, но есть минус не могу вывести на экран помогите hide и show срабатывают response все как надо но не alert не return результата не дают заранее спасибо за помощь

```js
$(window).load(function() { //говорим скрипту что он сработает когда вся страница загрузится
  var ID = [];
  $('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function() {
    ID.push($(this).data('id'));
    console.log(ID);
  });
  $('#basket').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $(".compare_basket").show("slow");
    });
  $('.compare_basket').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $(".compare_basket").hide("slow");
    });
  $('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $("#basket").show("slow"); // показываем как откроется форма
    console.log(ID);
    $.ajax({ // сам ajax запрос
        url: "myscript.php", // обработчик на php 
        data: {id: ID}, // даные которые передатся
        type: "POST", // метод
        
      })
      .done(function(data) { //отладочный запрос по которому заносятся данные 
       // выводим отладочную информацию
        alert(ID)
      });


  });
})
```

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $result = count($id);
    $err = array();
    if ($result > 3)
    {
     $err[] = "Можно сранивать не более трех модель";
    }
    if (count($err) == 0)
    {
        echo json_encode($id);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    elseif (count($err) > 0) {
     echo json_encode($err);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ // сам ajax запрос
    url: "myscript.php", // обработчик на php 
    data: {id: ID}, // даные которые передатся
    type: "POST", // метод
    success: function(e){ alert(e); }, // если запрос удачный выводим то что вернул скрипт php
    error: function(er){ alert(er); }, // если запрос не удался выводим ошибку
  })
```

Comment: не появляется алерт

Comment: Добавил вывод ошибки при неудачном запросе

Comment: не выводит ошибку в консоли